# How to send a PATCH request using ASIHTTPRequest on iOS

Tags: ios, rest, asihttprequest, patch, tastypie

I'm currently developing an iOS app that interacts with a server (in django) via a RESTful API (tastypie).

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest to send the requests off. However, it doesn't appear to support PATCH requests (I'm using tastypie).

I'm current writing something like this:

```
[request setRequestMethod:@"PATCH"];
```

But the server doesn't seem to be getting any response... what am I doing something wrong?

I know my code works because when I change it to GET or POST it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the request method to POST and adding the X-HTTP-Method-Override header with the PATCH value?

Comment: doesn't seem to work... is it [request addRequestHeader:@"X-HTTP-Method-Override" value:@"PATCH"]; ?

Comment: Yes. It has to be supported by the web service.

Comment: thanks for the info. It turns out, heroku doesn't support PATCH requests